# Object has no a 'get_category_display'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to display product detail page using drf but I keep running into one error after another.

```
urls.py

path('product/<int:id>', views.product_detail_view.as_view(), name='product-detail'),

models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_owner")
    item = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="brand")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/products/")
    label = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='', blank=True, null=True)

serializers.py
class product_detail_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("id", "categories", "item", "slug", "image")
    lookup_field = "id"
        
    def get_category(self, obj):
        return obj.get_category_display()

views.py
class product_detail_view(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = product_detail_serializer
    lookup_field = "id"
```

The error I'm getting now is `'Product has no attribute 'get_category_display'`

Please how do I fix this error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Pls check, I have added the error message to the post

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining the id inside the product_detail_serializer class then include it in the url patterns path like this:

```py
serializers.py
class product_detail_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

Then include the id in the urlpatherns path

```py
path('product/<int:id>',views.product_detail_view.as_view(),name='product
detail'),
```

Comment: I still got the same error after adding adding `id=serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)` to serializers.py.

Comment: @C-Bizz I  think the error is arising  because you included the  "id" in the class Meta class while it doesn't exist in the Product class, also get rid of the look_field =  "id"

Comment: Even after getting rid of the 'id' in the Meta class the same error occurs. I have also removed the lookup field,

Answer (score 0):

I basically can't explain why this worked. I used the serializer for `product` instead of creating another serializer for the product detail page.